# Is there a way to put a button in the home app (in Catalina) on the desktop?

Tags: homekit

I would like quick access to a home app button either in the dock or on the desktop.

I tried dragging a button to the desktop.  I explored the menus.  I cannot find a way to do it.

It would also be nice if there was also an option for home controls in Mojave (though I know the Home app is Catalina+ only), but the button I'd like to use is for controlling my KVM setup (I still use a 32 bit app on a Mac Mini running Mojave).  But at least getting from the Catalina Mac to the Mojave Mac would be convenient.

Ways I currently can switch: Siri command, Home.app, Node-RED, and manually switching the 4 devices involved in my setup that the 2 computers share (USB switch, HDMI switch, Stereo connection, TV's HDMI channel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If you have Node-RED running on a Mac or Raspberry Pi, you can save a simple AppleScript, such as the one below, as an application:

```
set webhookurl to "http://raspberrypi.local:1880/smartplugon"
set shellTxt to "curl -X GET " & " \"" & webhookurl & "\" > /dev/null"
do shell script shellTxt
```

which can make a simple webhook call to your Node-RED instance, anytime you run it.  Node-RED can be set to listen on a URL such as the one above which watches for calls to a location you name, e.g. `smartplugon` (which you define in a Node-RED workflow using an `http in` node).

Then, by installing `node-red-contrib-homekit-bridged` in Node-RED, you can link Node-RED to Siri.  The nodes you create using that homekit-bridged node will show up on your phone, and can receive on/off commands via the webhook call (which is, as in this case, called by the applescript application we made above).  You then connect the homekit-bridged node to a device-specific node, such as a WeMo node, which actually issues the on/off command to the device.

Note, this does not work with an Apple home pod or an iPad.  But, you can transfer all of your smart devices to Node-RED and use it as your hub.  Then you can do much more than what the Apple ecosystem allows.

Here's an example of the workflow to receive the webhook call and turn on a smart plug (the actual smartplug control is not included, so all this does is change the button status on your phone - adding the device controls is left to you):

```
[
    {
        "id": "2eeb6d1c.b427aa",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "home example",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "dfce471f.cf9df8",
        "type": "http in",
        "z": "2eeb6d1c.b427aa",
        "name": "Smart Plug On",
        "url": "/smartplugon",
        "method": "get",
        "upload": false,
        "swaggerDoc": "",
        "x": 310,
        "y": 180,
        "wires": [
            [
                "6c1cc05b.d47088",
                "18cbf86.372f988"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6c1cc05b.d47088",
        "type": "http response",
        "z": "2eeb6d1c.b427aa",
        "name": "Response",
        "statusCode": "200",
        "headers": {},
        "x": 470,
        "y": 160,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "18cbf86.372f988",
        "type": "template",
        "z": "2eeb6d1c.b427aa",
        "name": "On",
        "field": "payload",
        "fieldType": "msg",
        "format": "handlebars",
        "syntax": "plain",
        "template": "{\"On\":true}",
        "output": "json",
        "x": 450,
        "y": 200,
        "wires": [
            [
                "645fcc0c.a3cc84"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "645fcc0c.a3cc84",
        "type": "homekit-service",
        "z": "2eeb6d1c.b427aa",
        "isParent": true,
        "bridge": "f2691ed1.345838",
        "parentService": "",
        "name": "Smart Plug",
        "serviceName": "Outlet",
        "topic": "",
        "filter": false,
        "manufacturer": "Default Manufacturer",
        "model": "Default Model",
        "serialNo": "0001",
        "cameraConfigVideoProcessor": "",
        "cameraConfigSource": "",
        "cameraConfigStillImageSource": "",
        "cameraConfigMaxStreams": "",
        "cameraConfigMaxWidth": "",
        "cameraConfigMaxHeight": "",
        "cameraConfigMaxFPS": "",
        "cameraConfigMaxBitrate": "",
        "cameraConfigVideoCodec": "",
        "cameraConfigAudioCodec": "",
        "cameraConfigAudio": false,
        "cameraConfigPacketSize": "",
        "cameraConfigVerticalFlip": false,
        "cameraConfigHorizontalFlip": false,
        "cameraConfigMapVideo": "",
        "cameraConfigMapAudio": "",
        "cameraConfigVideoFilter": "",
        "cameraConfigAdditionalCommandLine": "",
        "cameraConfigDebug": false,
        "cameraConfigInterfaceName": "",
        "characteristicProperties": "{\"On\":true}",
        "x": 590,
        "y": 200,
        "wires": [
            [],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "f2691ed1.345838",
        "type": "homekit-bridge",
        "z": "",
        "bridgeName": "NodeRED HomeKitD",
        "pinCode": "111-11-111",
        "port": "",
        "allowInsecureRequest": false,
        "manufacturer": "Default Manufacturer",
        "model": "Default Model",
        "serialNo": "Default Serial Number",
        "customMdnsConfig": false,
        "mdnsMulticast": true,
        "mdnsInterface": "",
        "mdnsPort": "",
        "mdnsIp": "",
        "mdnsTtl": "",
        "mdnsLoopback": true,
        "mdnsReuseAddr": true,
        "allowMessagePassthrough": false
    }
]
```

Note, you can import the workflow in Node-RED by copying the above flow, selecting `Import` from the Node-RED menu on the top right.

You would then create an application for each action you want to perform and change the last part of the URL in the AppleScript and create a new `http in` node connected to a different `homekit-bridged` device.